# How to create any location 3D tile layers in Cesium map

Tags: openlayers, cesiumjs

I want to create my location 3D tile layers for cesium map. but how to create i have no idea because i am beginner in cesium.
So anyone know how to create 3D tile layers for any specific location give your response.

I have this location 3D tile map

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=I3S%20IntegratedMesh%20Layer.html&label=DataSources

[image]

I want to create this location 3D tile data source. near San Francisco location

[image]

Comment: You can see San Francisco area 3d tile build demo.  https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Cesium%20OSM%20Buildings.html
by terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain()

Comment: @BenchVue Hello Bench Please see My Image how does the building look like Google Earth 3D view but you are using OSM layers. I want building look like Google Earth 3D view.

Comment: You need to know an asset Id from Cesium or your own 3d tiles files for San Francisco Area. This example will show to demo.

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=3D%20Tiles%20Photogrammetry.html

Comment: How we can create own 3D tile for our location building and what about asset Id from Cesium how we get asset id for our location.

Comment: Your own 3d Tiles, single metadata (3dtiles.json) and multiple binary 3d tiles files (*.3dbm). your own local files server and access your map client. This is a detail [specification](https://github.com/CesiumGS/3d-tiles). To get an asset Id, you need to ask Cesium company.

Comment: @BenchVue Can you tell me how we can create 3D Building view in ol-cesium map like Google earth 3D view.

Comment: I don't know `ol-cesium` supports 3d tiles., No experience.

Comment: Ok, in Cesium Map how we create 3D Building view like Google Earth 3D view Please.

Comment: Same question. see upper 2nd my comment.

Comment: Yes, I am beginner in Cesium so i don't know ho we create 3D building view.

Comment: @BenchVue Hello how we can create this type map for our location.
https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=I3S%203D%20Object%20Layer.html&label=All

Comment: You can see some 3d tile already that your [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=I3S%203D%20Object%20Layer.html) around Sales force Park by ArcGISTiledElevationTerrainProvider(), if you zoom in and close that park, You can see it.

Comment: Yes, But How we create like this for other location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is San Francisco area 3d tile map with `ArcGISTiledElevationTerrainProvider()`

Example code copied from Cesium demo [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=I3S%203D%20Object%20Layer.html)
And replace url of Indexed 3D Scene (I3S) layer

From

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/SanFrancisco_3DObjects_1_7/SceneServer/layers/0
```

To

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/SanFrancisco_Bldgs/SceneServer?cacheKey=90e21aeb68997279
```

I got from arcgis `San Francisco 3D Buildings` service in [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d3344ba99c3f4efaa909ccfbcc052ed5)

And arcgis map (Scene Service Viewer)

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/SanFrancisco_Bldgs/SceneServer?view=sceneview&f=html&cacheKey=90e21aeb68997279
```

Demo Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Cesium Example</title>
    <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.103/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.103/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        #cesiumContainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
    <script>
        Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = "<your Cesium Ion Token>;
        const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
            terrainProvider: new Cesium.createWorldTerrain(),
            animation: false,
            timeline: false,
        });
        // More datasets to tour can be added here...
        // The url passed to I3SDataProvider supports loading a single Indexed 3D Scene (I3S) layer (.<host>/SceneServer/layers/<id>) or a collection of scene layers (.<host>/SceneServer) from a SceneServer.
        const tours = {
            "San Francisco":
                "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/SanFrancisco_Bldgs/SceneServer?cacheKey=90e21aeb68997279"
                // "https://elevation3d.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldElevation3D/Terrain3D/ImageServer?f=json"
        };
        // Initialize a terrain provider which provides geoid conversion between gravity related (typically I3S datasets) and ellipsoidal based
        // height systems (Cesium World Terrain).
        // If this is not specified, or the URL is invalid no geoid conversion will be applied.
        // The source data used in this transcoding service was compiled from https://earth-info.nga.mil/#tab_wgs84-data and is based on EGM2008 Gravity Model
        const geoidService = new Cesium.ArcGISTiledElevationTerrainProvider({
            url:
                "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/EGM2008/ImageServer",
        });
        // Create i3s and Cesium3DTileset options to pass optional parameters useful for debugging and visualizing
        const cesium3dTilesetOptions = {
            skipLevelOfDetail: false,
            debugShowBoundingVolume: false,
        };
        const i3sOptions = {
            url: tours["San Francisco"],
            traceFetches: false, // for tracing I3S fetches
            geoidTiledTerrainProvider: geoidService, // pass the geoid service
            cesium3dTilesetOptions: cesium3dTilesetOptions, // options for internal Cesium3dTileset
        };

        // Create I3S data provider
        const i3sProvider = new Cesium.I3SDataProvider(i3sOptions);

        // Center camera on I3S once it's loaded
        i3sProvider.readyPromise.then(function () {
            const center = Cesium.Rectangle.center(i3sProvider.extent);
            center.height = 10000.0;
            viewer.camera.setView({
                destination: Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartographicToCartesian(center),
            });
        });

        // Add the i3s layer provider as a primitive data type
        viewer.scene.primitives.add(i3sProvider);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Result
[image]

[image]

[image]

Note, It only the grayed area.
[image]

Comment: thanks you, How we can add layers in this building like this red layers  https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=3D%20Tiles%20Photogrammetry%20Classification.html

Comment: I try to change color a `I3SDataProvider` style and `cesium3dTilesetOptions` add style but both did not works. Your pointing 3d tiles example is different with I3SDataProvider. I don't know how to change color for this case.